# Toggle visibility of expanded child in Row/Column/Flex without loosing child's state

Tags: flutter

Toggle visibility of expanded child, but child's state is lost when hidden:

```
Column(children: [
  if (isRedVisible)
    Expanded(
      child: Container(color: Colors.red),
    ),
  if (isBlueVisible)
    Expanded(
      child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
]);
```

Toggle visibility, but child is taking up space when hidden (which isn't what I want):

```
Column(children: [
  Expanded(
    child: Visibility(visible: isRedVisible, maintainState: true, child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
  ),
  Expanded(
    child: Visibility(visible: isBlueVisible, maintainState: true, child: Container(color: Colors.blue)),
  ),
]);
```

So, how to toggle expanded child's visibility without loosing state, so that child is not taking up space when hidden?

Answer (score 0):

try AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

```
 class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FooState createState() {
    return new FooState();
  }
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```